# How can I call a web2py controller from Android?

Tags: android, web2py

I know exactly how the MVC pattern works with web2py and how the view is rendered on a "Browser".

I now want to render the View on an Android Project. For e.g. I have my Andriod App which takes a username ( email ), password and I want to authenticate the credentials by using the web2py framework ( auth ). I can very easily do the above using the Browser as a View.

I am struggling to get it right with respect to Andriod Application. How can I expose the controller ( or controller function ) to the Andriod device?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't expose controller to Android. But what you can do is build REST web services on web2py to use the authentication module, and call the web service from Android app.